# Как указать с каким листом работать? Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Добрый день
Есть следующий код

```
function doGet(e)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1CikjuH1ZqXhvXUTRwTICd0u8DVtePSMpQ2ebv52Y8KU");
  var n=sheet.getRange("Z1").getValue()+2;
  var d = new Date(); 
  sheet.getRange("A"+n).setValue(d);
  sheet.getRange("B"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p1);
  sheet.getRange("C"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p2);
  sheet.getRange("D"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p3);
  sheet.getRange("E"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p4);
  sheet.getRange("Z1").setValue(n-1);
}
```

Он записывает данные в Таблицу Google через get-запрос
Но записывает он всегда в первый лист таблицы
Как указать в коде в какой лист нужно записывать данные?

Я копал в сторону класа

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var first = ss.getSheetByName("first");
 first.activate();
```

Но до конца не докопал
Знает кто-то решение проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так вы задаёте лист, с которым вам нужно работать:

```
...
var sheetname = sheet.getSheetByName('data'); // выбираем лист "data"
```

Дальше вы можете использовать `sheetname` для дальнейших операций:

```
var range = sheetname.getRange("A1:B2"); // задаём диапазон на листе "data"
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста
function doGet(e)
{var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("тут айди");
  var sheetname = sheet.getSheetByName('data');
  var n=sheetname.getRange("Z1").getValue()+2;
  var d = new Date(); 
  sheetname.getRange("A"+n).setValue(d);
  sheetname.getRange("B"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p1);
  sheetname.getRange("C"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p2);
  sheetname.getRange("D"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p3);
  sheetname.getRange("E"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p4);
  sheetname.getRange("Z1").setValue(n-1);
}

Но данные записываются в первый лист
Хотя лист data есть, что не так?

Comment: Лист "data" не первый? На всякий случай спрашиваю.

Comment: Лист data второй

Comment: Спасибо большое пошла запись
Просто неккоректно сохранил

Comment: А не знаете как можно имя листа передать через get запрос?
сейчас он выглядит так
https://script.google.com/macros/s/ключ/exec?p1=данные&p2=данные2

Как бы еще и через какой то параметр указывать название листа с которым нужно работать?

Comment: Не знаю. Задайте дополнительный вопрос, кто-нибудь подскажет.